# Print something on terminal if macOS app (GUI based) opens from terminal

Tags: objective-c, macos, jenkins

I want to print something on terminal if macOS app (GUI based) opens from terminal.

---

### Situation

I'm building a macOS app that can build iOS project and upload IPA file on Dropbox. Everything working fine but now I want to setup this with Jenkins. For this, I'll launch the app from URISchemes with Workspace path, like this -

```
open -W appbox://build?/Volumes/LongTime/TestProject/ABAppStoreTest
```

This is working good too. But I can't able to print anything on terminal. All I want, to print current build output on terminal.

[image]

---

### AppBox Source Code

If you want to test this situation with appbox, you can pull the code from development branch https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/AppBox-iOSAppsWirelessInstallation/tree/development

You'll also need to fill out this plist and put in your main project directory
https://github.com/vineetchoudhary/AppBox-iOSAppsWirelessInstallation/blob/development/AppBox/appbox.plist

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Applications initiated with *open* are not tied to the terminal app. It will not show the output.

You can try to execute directly the binary inside the bundle.  This way it will be executed as a child process, and his output will be shown:

```
AppBox.app/Contents/MacOS/AppBox build=/Users/emp195/Documents/ProjectWorking/jenkinstest
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I never thought that it'd be so simple.

Answer (score 0):

In your methods

```
-(void)handleProjectAtPath:(NSString *)projectPath
```

or wherever you handle the opening of the project at the path give as a parameter, simply `NSLog` the `CFBundleVersion` located in the Info.plist of the IPA (must be unzipped before it can be accessed)

Answer (score -1):

I, Archive the application and copy it in the Applications folder, then in Terminal I write: open /Applications/myApp. If your app has NSLogs or printf sentences it's are show in Terminal. No matter if the app is Sandboxed or not.

Comment: Not working...

I've tried this `open /Applications/AppBox.app  --args build=/Users/emp195/Documents/ProjectWorking/jenkinstes` and this `open -W /Applications/AppBox.app  --args build=/Users/emp195/Documents/ProjectWorking/jenkinstest`